# Checkbox not working in a Django form (bug?)

Tags: django, forms

In [this Django program](https://github.com/vporton/django-checkbox-bug) the checkbox in the form is not shown. I want to show it.

Please explain what is my error.

Django version 1.10.3.

I tried to render the form this way:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Organization name')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Organization email')
    trial_period = forms.CheckboxInput()

# The view method
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse(str(checkbox_test.forms.MyForm()))
```

The view shows name and email but no checkbox for `trial_period`.

Comment: Can you write down what have you tried so far?

Comment: Try adding a widget to your form: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxinput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxinput)

Comment: @joshlsullivan I don't understand what you mean by "adding a widget to your form". Your link points to `CheckboxInput` class which I already use. So I don't understand what you suggest to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forms.CheckboxInput` is a widget - not a form field.

I think what you're looking for is a `forms.BooleanField`

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Organization name')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Organization email')
    trial_period = forms.BooleanField()
```